# .wav sounds not playing in Java

Tags: java, file, audio, wav, audio-player

I am currently using this function to play .WAV files

```
public void playSound(String sound){
    try {
         // Open an audio input stream.
         URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(sound);
         AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
         // Get a sound clip resource.
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.start();
      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

The problem is that no sound is being played when I call the function on a file, no errors or exceptions are thrown or whatsoever the program just starts  and stops, no sound plays, I tried with a lot of different .WAV files with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programm stops before it has time to play the sound since start is non-blocking.

Try the following :

```
clip.start();
clip.drain();
clip.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public void sound() {
    try{

        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("./sounds/player-laser.wav"));
        Clip test = AudioSystem.getClip();  

        test.open(ais);
        test.loop(0);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```